# What are key points to determine SQL Server version cost?

Tags: sql-server

I have to design website to start migration of sql server from one version to another and based on client database requirements we will tell him the cost of this migration and which sql server version is best to use?

Comment: You aren't actually asking a question. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some important factors in choosing SQL Server version and edition on following topics:

- How many CPU cores it can utilize
- How much RAM it can utilize
- What key feature it supports. for instance some versions do not support columnstore index or partitioning. Read the feature list.
- Number/Size of supported databases
- AFAIK some editions have better query optimization. (I'm not sure though)
- Do you need `BI` feature? How about `Replication`, High Availability features like `Mirroring`? `Always On`? `Data Encryption`? `Data/Index Compression`?

You need to know, volume of data and concurrent users to decide. 
Some features are critical for large volume databases and some are not.